# Prolog remove function - almost working

Tags: prolog

The following predicate is `remove(L,X,R)`, where `L` is a list, `X` is an element to remove from the list. The code returns the correct list, however it always also returns false afterwards.

I can't find the place where two of the rules can be applied during runtime.

```
remove([],X,[]) :- !. 
remove([X|T],X,L1) :- remove(T,X,L1). 
remove([H|T],X,[H|L1]) :- \+(X==H), remove(T,X,L1).
```

Sample query with expected result:

```
?- remove([1,2,3,4],3,R).
R = [1, 2, 4] ; 
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Teaching/Resources/COMS30106/labs/tracer.html - SWI-prolog has tracing/debugging mode. In my opinion, cmd-line debugger is better than the visual one.

EDIT:

```
remove([],X,[]) :- !. 
remove([X|T],X,L1) :- !, remove(T,X,L1).          <-- cut was added
remove([H|T],X,[H|L1]) :- remove(T,X,L1).         <-- condition was deleted
```

The above code should be allright. No warranties though.

Comment: Thank you - I'll use it to debug and find my problem.

Comment: Well, you get the result as you wrote above because:

when the prolog recurses to the element 3 it has two choices: 
use second predicate or use third predicate. Usage of the second predicate leads to the result R = [1, 2, 4] ; ... which is what you want. But usage of the third predicate (this predicate is used when you want more results from SWI-prolog) leads to the false result - why? Because the unification on the head of predicate is used (and therefore H and X has the same value 3) and then the condition \+(X==H) is checked which fails => therefore result "false.".

Comment: Thank you! Thats excellent! I wasn't aware that you are able to cut on a line with other calls! I have tested your code and it works fabulously.

Answer (score 2):

If your Prolog system supports [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), you can preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by proceeding as follows.
Using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)   [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and reified inequality predicate [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915), we can write:

```
remove(Xs0,E,Xs) :- tfilter(dif(E),Xs0,Xs).
```

Quick check if it works:

```
?- tfilter(dif(3),[1,2,3,4],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,4].                     % succeeds deterministically
```

`tfilter/3` and `dif/3` are **monotone**, so 
we get sound answers, even for general queries:

```
?- remove([A,B,C],3,Xs).
Xs = [     ],     A=3 ,     B=3 ,     C=3  ;
Xs = [    C],     A=3 ,     B=3 , dif(C,3) ;
Xs = [  B  ],     A=3 , dif(B,3),     C=3  ;
Xs = [  B,C],     A=3 , dif(B,3), dif(C,3) ;
Xs = [A    ], dif(A,3),     B=3 ,     C=3  ;
Xs = [A,  C], dif(A,3),     B=3 , dif(C,3) ;
Xs = [A,B  ], dif(A,3), dif(B,3),     C=3  ;
Xs = [A,B,C], dif(A,3), dif(B,3), dif(C,3) ;
false.
```