# Find powers of 2 in a list Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, clpz

I'm trying to create a list in Prolog (SWI Prolog) and check which numbers are powers of 2 and second find how many times a specific number is in the list (in this example I'm trying to find how many times the number 3 is in the list). 
For a example, if you ask

```
?- check([0,2,3,-5,-2,1,8,7,4], MULT2, THREE).
```

you should see

```
MULT2=[2,8,4] 
THREE=1
```

My first try to find a solution is to search the list with head and doing head mod 2 = 0 to find all numbers which are powers of 2, but something went wrong and I only get "false" as an answer.

Comment: You need to show your coding attempt. Also, is there a reason you are doing powers of 2 and frequency of a given number in a single predicate? They really are two different ideas and would make sense as two different predicates. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: `MULT2=[2,1,8,4]` would be the correct answer for `MULT2` in this case.

Comment: I 'm studying Prolog at University I am new in this programming language and I want to learn more things, but this task is for me to understand this difficult (for myself part of Prolog) lists. My previous task was to split the array, and I understand many things. But now I m trying to find how can I crete a predicate to do multiple things. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can find the "powers of two" in logically-pure way!

Using [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) 4.3.5, `library(reif)` and `library(clpz)`:

```
:- use_module([library(reif), library(clpz)]).

power_of_two_t(I, T) :-
   L #= min(I,1),
   M #= I /\ (I-1),
   call((L = 1, M = 0), T).      % using (=)/3 and (',')/3 of library(reif)
```

Sample query<sup>1</sup> using meta-predicate [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053194/4609915) in combination with `power_of_two_t/2`:

```
?- tfilter(power_of_two_t, [0,2,3,-5,-2,1,8,7,4], Ps).
Ps = [2,1,8,4].                  % succeeds deterministically
```

Here's a more general query suggested by a comment:

```
?- tfilter(power_of_two_t, [X], Ps).
   Ps = [X], 0#=X/\_A, _A+1#=X, X in 1..sup, _A in 0..sup
;  Ps = [], dif(_A,0), _A#=X/\_B, _B+1#=X, X in 1..sup, _B in 0..sup
;  Ps = [], dif(_A,1), _A#=min(X,1), _B#=X/\_C, _C+1#=X, X#>=_A, _A in inf..1.
```

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** The answer sequences shown above were brushed up to indicate the determinism of calls.</sup>

<sup>**Footnote 2:** To reproduce the results use `call_det/2` which is defined like this:</sup>

```
call_det(G_0, Det) :-
   call_cleanup(G_0, Flag = set),
   (  nonvar(Flag)
   -> Det = true
   ;  Det = false
   ).
```

Comment: Purer! As for `tfilter(power_of_two_t, [X], P)`.

Comment: @false. Thanks! I forgot about that one in the meantime ... Better now?

Comment: Cough, `det_call/1`. Why not use a purer shell for SICStus? [Cor.3](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/WDCor3#variable_names) has the missing functionality, and SICStus supports this [perfectly](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/variable_names)!

Comment: Since when I am non-deterministic? `det_call(false)` fails

Comment: @false. I feel the same. Is the name `goal_succeeds_deterministically/1` any better?

Comment: @mat. My first `clpz` code and I wouldn't even know how to express the same with SICStus' own clpfd :)

Comment: Wrong interface. Goals and determinism are something different!

Comment: @false. So `call_succeeds_deterministically/1`...?

Comment: You cannot overload failure of a goal with meaning something else.

Comment: @false. So using exceptions could be a proper way here?

Comment: What about `/2`?

Comment: @false. `call_det(G,Det)` succeeds if `G` succeeds, unifying `Det` with `true` or `false` accordingly?

Comment: @false. Yes, it looked it up recently. `call_semidet/1` throws an exception as soon as a second answer comes up, so it cannot be directly used when we want to know if a choicepoint (which may or may not lead to another answer) is left open, right?

Comment: So why did you suggest "using exceptions" and rename the concept? ((It's OK for /2)).

Comment: @false. I don't know. Presumably a mixture of ignorance and laziness;)

Comment: @mat. Wait a minute... is `popcount/1` supported by `clpz` on SICStus?

Comment: Note to self: `clpz:run_propagator//2` is the key: `clpz` covers *exactly* the same as `(is)/2` does, so `msb/1` is supported but `popcount/1` is not with SICStus.

Comment: Nts: help repair `library(reif)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange thing to have two such a different tasks to do in one predicate. You should probably have two separate predicates, one for counting number of powers of 2 and one to count 3s. Then you can combine them in one predicate like:

```
check(Nums, MULT2, THREE) :-
    count2powers(Nums, MULT2),
    count3s(Nums, THREE).
```

After that you can decompose further and have a separate predicate to check if a number is a power of 2:

```
is2power(1).
is2power(N) :-
    N > 0,
    N2 is N // 2,
    N2 * 2 =:= N,
    is2power(N2).
```

This is basic software engineering and this way you can build your program step by step and you will be able to ask more concrete and meaningful questions than just "The whole program returns false."