# Counting same element Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to count one element in the list and stop counting where different element appear, and jump to the next same element.

The answers should be like this:

```
?- count(a,[a,a,a,a,b,a,a,a],X).
X = [4,3]

?- count(a,[a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a],X).
X = [3,1,2,4]
```

The code I wrote for `count/3` is:

```
count(_, [], []).
count(X, [X | T], N) :-
   count(X, T, N1),
   !, 
   N is N1 + 1.
count(X, [_ | T], N) :-
   count(X, T, N).
```

I don't know how to make it return a list of number. 
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is quite vague, so I will just give a hint: use 4 arguments instead of 3: 2 for the input, 1 for the output, and 1 for the current number of elements found (which is initally 0).

Comment: @Kay, actually the list I input just contains two different elements, and i want to count one if it, and the result should just count that element. for example input count(a,[a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a], X). and output
X = [3,1,2,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in my answer is to keep the list of [run lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) open, and add a new element to it when a run is over:

```
count(_, [], []).
count(Item, [Head|Tail], Counts) :-
    count(Item, [Head|Tail], 0, Counts).
count(_, [], CurrentCount, [CurrentCount]).

count(Item, [Item|Tail], CurrentCount, Counts) :-
    CurrentCountP1 is CurrentCount + 1,
    count(Item, Tail, CurrentCountP1, Counts).
count(Item, [Head|Tail], CurrentCount, [CurrentCount|Counts]) :-
    dif(Head, Item),
    count(Item, Tail, 0, Counts).
```

```
?- count(a,[a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a], X).
X = [3, 1, 2, 4] ;
false.
```

Comment: When going from `count/3` to `count/4`, you can move the input list to the first argument and combine the last two clauses of `count/4` using an if-then-else. That will eliminate the spurious choice-point seen in the sample query (assuming first-argument indexing as typical in most systems, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can do it and preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!

In the following, we use the meta-predicates ([`splitlistIfAdj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915),
[`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915), and
[`maplist/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915)) and reified term equality/inequality predicates ([`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915) and [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915)).

Let's take `E = a` and `Xs0 = [a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a]` and build up `count/3` step by step:

1. First, let `Xs1` contain the *runs* of items in `Xs0`:

   ```
   ?- Xs0 = [a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a], splitlistIfAdj(dif,Xs0,Xs1).
   Xs0 = [ a,a,a,  b,  a,  b,  a,a,  b,  a,a,a,a ],
   Xs1 = [[a,a,a],[b],[a],[b],[a,a],[b],[a,a,a,a]].
   ```
2. The list of runs `Xs1` contains *all* runs. Let `Xs2` contain only the ones we are interested in:

   ```
   ?- Xs1 = [[a,a,a],[b],[a],[b],[a,a],[b],[a,a,a,a]], tfilter(\[X|_]^(X=a),Xs1,Xs2).
   Xs1 = [[a,a,a],[b],[a],[b],[a,a],[b],[a,a,a,a]],
   Xs2 = [[a,a,a],    [a],    [a,a],    [a,a,a,a]].
   ```
3. Almost done! At last, we map `Xs2` (a list of `E`-runs) to the respective run lengths `Xs`:

   ```
   ?- Xs2 = [[a,a,a],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a,a]], maplist(length,Xs2,Xs).
   Xs2 = [[a,a,a],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a,a]],
   Xs  = [      3,  1,    2,        4].
   ```

Now, let's put it all together!

```
count(E,Xs0,Xs) :-
    splitlistIfAdj(dif,Xs0,Xs1),
    tfilter(E+\[X|_]^(X=E),Xs1,Xs2),   % works for _any_ item E
    maplist(length,Xs2,Xs).
```

Let's run some queries:

```
?- count(a,[a,a,a,a,b,a,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [4,3].                            % succeeds deterministically
?- count(a,[a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [3,1,2,4].                        % succeeds deterministically
```

As the code is **monotone**, we get *logically sound answers* for more general queries, too:

```
?- count(E,[a,a,a,b,a,b,a,a,b,a,a,a,a],Xs).
Xs = [3,1,2,4], E = a              ;
Xs = [1,1,1],   E = b              ;
Xs = [],        dif(E,a), dif(E,b) .
```