# Strange results for list manipulation

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I'm trying to implement some predicates for list manipulation in Prolog.
Everything works as desired. For example

```
append([],Ys,Ys).
append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :- append(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Sample query:

```
?- append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],X).
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6].                   % OK
```

But I'm having trouble with the *'delete'*-predicate. Here's how it's implemented:

```
delete(X,[Y|Ys],Zs) :- X == Y, delete(X,Ys,Zs).
delete(X,[_X|Ys],[_Z|Zs]) :- delete(X,Ys,Zs).
delete(_X,[],[]).
```

Sample query with bad result:

```
?- delete(4,[1,2,3,4],X).
X = [_G8975, _G8978, _G8981].       % BAD
```

I've tested it with further input and it always returns a list of the expected length so in a way it works. But why am I getting only those cryptic _GXXXX and not the numbers?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cryptic way to get rid of cryptic variable names is to use [`numbervars/3`](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=numbervars/3), for example,

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_G2019, _G2022, _G2025].

?- length(X, 3), numbervars(X, 0, _).
X = [A, B, C].
```

Now to your `delete/3`. Apart from other minor problems, like unusual order of the arguments, unusual order of the clauses, etc, you have one major problem: in the second clause, you put a new, anonymous variable where the element of the original list should have been.

```
delete(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :- delete(X, Ys, Zs).
```

With this in the second clause, it sort of works:

```
?- delete(4, [1,2,3,4], L).
L = [1, 2, 3] .

?- delete(2, [1,2,3,4,2,3,4], L).
L = [1, 3, 4, 3, 4] .
```

There are further problems with your implementation. You can look at the [implementation](http://swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#delete/3) of the same predicate in `library(lists)` from SWI-Prolog: read the documentation, too!

Comment: Thank you very much ... I knew I overlooked something!

Comment: That `numbervars/3` trick no longer works in the presence of constraints.

Comment: `delete(1,[1],[1]).` succeeds, but it should fail.

Comment: @false My answer very clearly indicates that this implementation, even after my correction, has problems. The question did not warrant going deeper into it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues in your program. But first, as a beginner:

#### Stick to the pure monotonic subset of Prolog

In your program, you are using `(==)/2` which is no longer in that pure subset. In your case replace it by `(=)/2`.

#### Always look at all the answers

Prolog's top-level loops shows you only the first answer. You have to demand for more by pressing <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Your program with `(=)/2` gives (with more readable variables):

```
?- delete(4,[1,2,3,4],X).
   X = [_A,_B,_C]
;  X = [_A,_B,_C,_D]
;  false.
```

That is: Not only is the first answer unexpected, but there is a second one, with a list of same length as the original one. On the other hand, the first answer included the expected solution. So the program is rather too general.

#### Reduce the input size

```
?- delete(4,[4],L).
   L = []
;  L = [_A]
;  false.
```

The first answer seems now correct, but the second is entirely unexpected. That is, the definition is too general as witnessed by `delete(4,[4],[any])`

#### Specialize the program

To localize the program, specialize the program by introducing goals like **`false`**, and **`=`** as much as possible, and as long as `delete(4,[4],[any])` succeeds. I come up with:

```
?- delete(4,[4],[any]).

delete(X,[Y|Ys],Zs) :- false, X = Y, delete(X,Ys,Zs).
delete(X,[_X|Ys],[_Z|Zs]) :- X = 4, _X = 4, _Z = any,
   delete(X,Ys,Zs).
delete(_X,[],[]) :- _X = 4.
```

Now it should be evident that in this rule, `_X =4, _Z = any` should be rather the same, and `X = 4, _X = 4` should be different. Inequality is best expressed with `dif/2`.

```
delete(_X, [], []).
delete(X, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]) :-
   dif(X, Y),
   delete(X, Ys, Zs).
delete(X, [X|Ys], Zs) :-
   delete(X, Ys, Zs).
```

This definition can now be used in many ways. Like

```
?- delete(X,Xs,[1,2,3]).
   Xs = [1,2,3], dif(X,3), dif(X,2), dif(X,1)
;  Xs = [1,2,3,X], dif(X,3), dif(X,2), dif(X,1)
;  Xs = [1,2,3,X,X], dif(X,3), dif(X,2), dif(X,1)
; ... .
```

Note that there are now infinitely many answers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I'm always interested in tips and best practices...

Answer (score 4):

This answer is inspired by the **logically-pure** code that 
[@false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) presented [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27039107/4609915).

Let's use the meta-predicate [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915)
and reified term inequality [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and simply write:

```
?- Vs0 = [1,2,3,4], tfilter(dif(4),Vs0,Vs).
Vs0 = [1,2,3,4],
Vs  = [1,2,3  ].                      % succeeds deterministically

?- Vs0 = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4], tfilter(dif(2),Vs0,Vs).
Vs0 = [1,2,3,4,2,3,4],
Vs  = [1,  3,4,  3,4].                % succeeds deterministically
```

The implementation of `delete/3` boils down to:

```
delete(E,Vs0,Vs) :-
   tfilter(dif(E),Vs0,Vs).
```

Like @false's code this implementation is **monotone**, which makes the predicate versatile and enables you to get logically sound answers 
even when working with non-ground terms.

Finally, let's have a quite general query and look at all answers:

```
?- Vs0 = [X,Y,Z], delete(E,Vs0,Vs).
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z],     E=X ,     E=Y ,     E=Z , Vs = [     ] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z],     E=X ,     E=Y , dif(E,Z), Vs = [    Z] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z],     E=X , dif(E,Y),     E=Z , Vs = [  Y  ] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z],     E=X , dif(E,Y), dif(E,Z), Vs = [  Y,Z] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z], dif(E,X),     E=Y ,     E=Z , Vs = [X    ] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z], dif(E,X),     E=Y , dif(E,Z), Vs = [X,  Z] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z], dif(E,X), dif(E,Y),     E=Z , Vs = [X,Y  ] ;
Vs0 = [X,Y,Z], dif(E,X), dif(E,Y), dif(E,Z), Vs = [X,Y,Z].
```