# Prolog remove element from list,weird result

Tags: prolog

So I have this code to remove any element=X from a list.

```
remove(X,[],L).
remove(X,[X|T],Result):- remove(X,T,Result), !.
remove(X,[H|T],[H|Result]):- remove(X,T,Result).
```

But when I run it, in the result I get this weird `|_G19`.
I understand this has to do with the `[Head|Tail]` thingy
but I can't figure out a way to get rid of it from my result.

```
?- remove(2,[1,2,3,2,5,6,2],R).
R = [1, 3, 5, 6|_G19].
```

So what's wrong with it?
Why does this `6|_G19` appears?
How do I get rid of it?
Everything else is working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is on the first clause:

```
remove(X,[],L).
```

For you the second parameter is the output, so... in this base case, what is L? that's why you're getting _G19 (a pointer to something).

If you do directly:

```
remove(X,[],[]).
remove(X,[X|T],Result):- remove(X,T,Result).
remove(X,[H|T],[H|Result]):- remove(X,T,Result).
```

You should have it

Comment: No, that doesn't work,because then it just outputs false and nothing else.
And that's because it never succeeds without the first clause.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake writting it, it's edited now, it should work, the problem was still the base case

Comment: Yes now it works.
Yea, I didn't realize that technically L was an empty list there too.
Thank you.

Comment: `remove(a,[a],[a]).` succeeds. It should fail. Hint: use `dif/2`!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) in combination with 
[reified term inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664870/reification-of-term-equality-inequality) [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915):

```
remove(E,Xs,Ys) :- tfilter(dif(E),Xs,Ys).
```

Let's look at the query the OP gave in the question:

```
?- remove(2,[1,2,3,2,5,6,2],R).
R = [1,3,5,6].                     % succeeds deterministically
```

As both `tfilter/3` and `dif/3` are pure, we get sound answers if we ask more general queries:

```
?- remove(X,[A,B,C],Ys).
Ys = [     ],     X=A ,     X=B ,     X=C  ;
Ys = [    C],     X=A ,     X=B , dif(X,C) ;
Ys = [  B  ],     X=A , dif(X,B),     X=C  ;
Ys = [  B,C],     X=A , dif(X,B), dif(X,C) ;
Ys = [A    ], dif(X,A),     X=B ,     X=C  ;
Ys = [A,  C], dif(X,A),     X=B , dif(X,C) ;
Ys = [A,B  ], dif(X,A), dif(X,B),     X=C  ;
Ys = [A,B,C], dif(X,A), dif(X,B), dif(X,C).
```