# how to define the delete(X,L1,L2) relation using prolog where L2 is the resulted list in which item X is deleted from list L1

Tags: prolog

(1) how to define the `delete(X,L1,L2)` relation using Prolog where `L2` is the resulted list in which item `X` is deleted from list `L1`

(2) How to draw the derivation tree to answer the following query?

```
| ?- delete(3,[4,10,6,8,1,3,9],L)
```

[image: my attempt]

Comment: You should show your attempt at a solution to this problem. It also needs clarification: does `delete(X, L1, L2)` delete *one* instance of `X` from `L1`, or *all* instances?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand question #2. You asked for a derivation tree, and then you showed one.

Answer (score 3):

Save [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) by using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and reified disequality [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915):

```
?- tfilter(dif(3),[      4,    10,6,8,1,3,9],[4,10,6,8,1,9]).
true.
?- tfilter(dif(3),[3,3,3,4,3,3,10,6,8,1,3,9],[4,10,6,8,1,9]).
true.
```

Note this works just as fine with non-ground terms, too!

```
?- tfilter(dif(Y),[A,B],Xs).
Xs = [   ], Y = A,    A = B    ;
Xs = [  B], Y = A,    dif(A,B) ;
Xs = [A  ], Y = B,    dif(B,A) ;
Xs = [A,B], dif(Y,B), dif(Y,A).
```

Comment: what u mean by false..it should be true..isn't it??..When i compile it in SWI it gets the answer as true. and when i run the program it gets the answer as [4,10,6,8,1,9] . So what u mean as False??

Comment: @thsumia. I was referring to the user named "false". I hope that did not cause too much confusion.