# Prolog two list intersection - why does it keep checking?

Tags: prolog

I need to find elements which exist in both lists S1 and S2 and I need to print out these elements (R).
The problem is that when I type `bendri([a,b,c,d],[d,b,e],R)`, it returns the correct result `[b,d]`, but it doesn't stop. If you press ; symbol, then it keeps on checking again and returns `b`, after that - `d`.

Why is this happening? It should only return `[b,d]` and end its job.

```
bendri(S1,S2,R) :-
    skaiciavimai(S1,S2,R).

skaiciavimai([],_,[]).
skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, [First|Rest]) :-
    member(First, S2),
    skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
skaiciavimai([_|Tail], S2, Rest) :-
    skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
```

Comment: Have you tried using `trace.` to see which predicate it redoes?

Comment: Furthermore can you translate what `bendri` and `skaiciavimai` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the third clause of `skaiciavimai/3` also succeeds on backtracking even if the second clause succeeded. I guess you want to skip the third clause if the second clause succeeds.

To do that you can add a check in the third clause:

```
skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, Rest) :-
    \+ (member(First, S2)),
    skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
```

so that the third clause fails if the head of the first list is found in `S2`.

Comment: s(X) for using `(\+)/1` in the third clause, not a cut in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Simple story: `;` means that Prolog should look for alternatives, and since `bendri(A,B,C)` is defined as *"`C` is **a** list of elements that occur in both `A` and `B`"* (according to your definition), it will print all possible results. You can see this on the `trace` below (added below because the trace is rather long).

## Resolution

The problem is that you introduce a decision point in your `skaiciavimai/3` predicate: indeed given the first argument is a list with at least one element (of the form `[_|_]`), the Prolog environment can select both the second and third clause: after it has tried the `skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, [First|Rest])` clause successfully, it can also aim to select the next clause `skaiciavimai([_|Tail], S2, Rest)`. Since there is no predicate that prevents that selection from being successful, it will also find a solution omitting the head element. You can solve this by adding an additional constraint in the last clause:

```
skaiciavimai([],_,[]).
skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, [First|Rest]) :-
    member(First, S2),
    skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, Rest) :-
    \+ member(First,S2),
    skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
```

The `\+` means something like the *logical not* (although one must be careful, because not is a problematic topic in *Logic Programming*). So now we prevent Prolog from selecting the third clause successfully given `First` is a member of `S2`. When you use this code the result of your query is:

```
?- bendri([a,b,c,d],[d,b,e],R).
R = [b, d] ;
false.
```

We have thus altered the definition of `skaiciavimai/3` it now reads something like: *"`C` is a list of all elements that occur in `A` that occur in `B` as well."* since in order to omit an element from `A` (third clause), it should not be a member of `B`.

## Towards a better predicate

In Prolog the aim is to make predicate *multidirectional*. Indeed, you want to be able to call predicates in different directions. `bendri/3` can be implemented such that `bendri(A,B,[a,c])` also returns `A = [a, c], B = [a, c] ;`, etc. (which is the case here). In designing predicates one needs to take into account multiple uses of the predicate.

## Trace

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- bendri([a,b,c,d],[d,b,e],R).
   Call: (6) bendri([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], _G360) ? creep
   Call: (7) skaiciavimai([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], _G360) ? creep
   Call: (8) lists:member(a, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) lists:member(a, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Redo: (7) skaiciavimai([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], _G360) ? creep
   Call: (8) skaiciavimai([b, c, d], [d, b, e], _G360) ? creep
   Call: (9) lists:member(b, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) lists:member(b, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Call: (9) skaiciavimai([c, d], [d, b, e], _G448) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(c, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lists:member(c, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Redo: (9) skaiciavimai([c, d], [d, b, e], _G448) ? creep
   Call: (10) skaiciavimai([d], [d, b, e], _G448) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:member(d, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) lists:member(d, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Call: (11) skaiciavimai([], [d, b, e], _G451) ? creep
   Exit: (11) skaiciavimai([], [d, b, e], []) ? creep
   Exit: (10) skaiciavimai([d], [d, b, e], [d]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) skaiciavimai([c, d], [d, b, e], [d]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) skaiciavimai([b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b, d]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) skaiciavimai([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b, d]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) bendri([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b, d]) ? creep
R = [b, d] ;
   Redo: (11) lists:member(d, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Fail: (11) lists:member(d, [d, b, e]) ? creep
   Redo: (10) skaiciavimai([d], [d, b, e], _G448) ? creep
   Call: (11) skaiciavimai([], [d, b, e], _G448) ? creep
   Exit: (11) skaiciavimai([], [d, b, e], []) ? creep
   Exit: (10) skaiciavimai([d], [d, b, e], []) ? creep
   Exit: (9) skaiciavimai([c, d], [d, b, e], []) ? creep
   Exit: (8) skaiciavimai([b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) skaiciavimai([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) bendri([a, b, c, d], [d, b, e], [b]) ? creep
R = [b] ;
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer follows up on @gusbro's answer... Why not preserve logical purity? It's easy!

Simply replace the third clause by:

```
skaiciavimai([First|Tail], S2, Rest) :-
   non_member(First, S2),
   skaiciavimai(Tail, S2, Rest).
```

And define `non_member/2` like this:

```
non_member(X, Es) :-
   maplist(dif(X), Es).
```

Comment: What about an answer using `memberd_t/3`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a follow-up to [this logically-pure answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) presented earlier.

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

bendri(Es, Fs, Xs) :-
%          ^^
%          ||
%          |+----------------+\
%          ||                ||
%          vv                vv
   tfilter(Fs+\E^memberd_t(E,Fs), Es, Xs).
%            ^^
%            || 
%            \+------------------ Fs has global scope
```

Sample query given by the OP:

```
?- bendri([a,b,c,d], [d,b,e], Xs).
Xs = [b,d].
```