# How can i delete every item from list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

I want to define a relation `del_all(X, L, L1)` for removing all items `X` (if any) from list `L`.

Sample query:

```
?- del_all(a, [a,b,a,c,d,a], L1).
L1 = [b, c, d].                           % expected answer
```

Comment: You want to delete all *equal* items or all *unifiable* items? Or is your list elements *always* ground, making the distinction mute?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version that combines `(=)/2` and `dif/2`:

```
list_without([], _, []).
list_without([X|Xs], H, Ys0) :-
   if_(X = H, Ys0 = Ys, Ys0 = [H|Ys]),
   list_without(Xs, H, Ys).
```

It uses [`if_/3`](/a/27358600/772868)

Answer (score 1):

```
dele_all(X, [], []).
dele_all(X, [H|T], R) :-
   H = X,
   dele_all(X, T, R).
dele_all(X, [H|T], [H|R]) :-
   dif(H, X),
   dele_all(X, T, R).
```

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning list items according to some given criterion is a common idiom in Prolog.

Using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) in combination with [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) we can simply query:

```
?- tfilter(dif(a), [a,b,a,c,d,a], L1).
L1 = [b,c,d].                            % expected result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
del_all(_,[],[]).
del_all(Item,[Item|Rest],RRest) :-
    !,
    del_all(Item,Rest,RRest).
del_all(Item,[OtherItem|Rest],[OtherItem|RRest]) :-
    del_all(Item,Rest,RRest).
```

Simple as that.