# Most general higher-order constraint describing a sequence of integers ordered with respect to a relation

Tags: prolog, clpfd, topology, meta-predicate

In CLP(FD), we frequently need to state: "This is a list of integers and finite domain variables in (sometimes: *strictly*) ascending/descending order."

Is there any CLP(FD) system that provides a general (parametrisable) built-in constraint for this task?

SWI-Prolog provides a constraint called `chain/2`, which is similar to what I am looking for. However, the name is slightly too specific to encompass all relations that the constraint can describe (example: `#<` is not a partial order but admissible in `chain/2`, leading to the sequence — taken as a set of integers — no longer counting as a chain as defined in mathematical order-theory). Hence, the name does not fully describe what the constraint actually implements.

Please give the *most general* definition with respect to the usual binary CLP(FD) constraints — or a suitable subset that contains at least `#<`, `#>`, `#=<` and `#>=` — *including* the proper name according to the algebraic structure the constraint defines. The condition imposed is that the constraint describe an *actual* mathematical structure that has a proper name in the literature.

As a start, consider with SICStus Prolog or SWI:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

connex(Relation_2, List) :-
    connex_relation(Relation_2),
    connex_(List, Relation_2).

connex_relation(#=).
connex_relation(#<).
connex_relation(#=<).
connex_relation(#>).
connex_relation(#>=).

connex_([], _).
connex_([L|Ls], Relation_2) :-
    foldl(adjacent(Relation_2), Ls, L, _).

adjacent(Relation_2, X, Prev, X) :- call(Relation_2, Prev, X).
```

Sample cases:

```
?- connex(#<, [A,B,C]).
A#=<B+-1,
B#=<C+-1.

?- connex(#=, [A,B,C]).
A = B, B = C,
C in inf..sup.

?- maplist(connex(#<), [[A,B],[C,D]]).
A#=<B+-1,
C#=<D+-1.
```

Notice that it would even be admissible to allow `#\=`, because the relation would *still* describe a connex as known in mathematical order-theory. Hence, the code above is not most general with respect to the usual binary CLP(FD) constraints.

Comment: s(X)! Nice naming convention for partial goals (`Relation_2`)!

Answer (score 9):

Hoogle was not very useful, but [Hayoo is!](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28x-%3Ex-%3EBool%29+-%3E+[x]+-%3E+Bool)

#### [`foldcmpl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths-0.4.5/docs/src/Math-Core-Utils.html#foldcmpl)

so this is a special form of fold for a list, but it does not apply `length list` times but one time less.

#### [`isSortedBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:isSortedBy)

is not entirely general in its name, but in its signature. Maybe insisting on the most general name is not that helpful. Otherwise we just have entities all over?

The definition reads:

> The isSortedBy function returns True iff the predicate returns true for all adjacent pairs of elements in the list.

Maybe: `all_adjacent_pairs(R_2, Xs)`. which sounds a bit after having a looping construct that has `adjacent_pair` as some modifier.

Comment: The *predicate* should be as general as possible under the given restrictions. Its *name* should be as specific as possible, while still encompassing all use cases. `foldcmpl` goes (also quite literally) in the right direction! `foldadjl` ...?

Answer (score 5):

This is inspired by a toolbox of functional higher-order idioms I once implemented. Back then I found the corner cases agonizing, I still do today:) Also, finding good names is always an issue...

Consider meta-predicate `mapadj/4`:

```
mapadj(Relation_4,As,Bs,Cs) :-
   list_list_list_mapadj(As,Bs,Cs,Relation_4).

list_list_list_mapadj([],[],[],_).
list_list_list_mapadj([A|As],Bs,Cs,Relation_4) :-
   list_prev_list_list_mapadj(As,A,Bs,Cs,Relation_4).

list_prev_list_list_mapadj([],_,[],[],_).
list_prev_list_list_mapadj([A1|As],A0,[B|Bs],[C|Cs],Relation_4) :-
   call(Relation_4,A0,A1,B,C),
   list_prev_list_list_mapadj(As,A1,Bs,Cs,Relation_4).
```

Sample uses:

```
z_z_sum_product(X,Y,Sum,Product) :-
   Sum     #= X + Y,
   Product #= X * Y.

:- mapadj(z_z_sum_product,[],       [],     []).
:- mapadj(z_z_sum_product,[1],      [],     []).

:- mapadj(z_z_sum_product,[1,2],    [3],    [2]).
:- mapadj(z_z_sum_product,[1,2,3],  [3,5],  [2,6]).
:- mapadj(z_z_sum_product,[1,2,3,4],[3,5,7],[2,6,12]).
```

I'm aware of the rift in the corner cases `As = []`and `As = [_]`, still I feel this is as close to "for all adjacent list items" as it gets.

Also, all of this can easily be extended:

- down to `mapadj/2` (akin to `chain/2`, except for the type-check with singleton lists)
- sideways, with an additional state argument, to `foldadjl/n`, `scanadjl/n`

Regarding names: IMO the `l` / `r` suffix is required with `fold` / `scan`, but not with `map`.

---

#### Edit 2015-04-26

Here comes the before-mentioned `foldadjl/4`:

```
foldadjl(Relation_4,Xs) -->
   list_foldadjl(Xs,Relation_4).

list_foldadjl([],_) -->
   [].
list_foldadjl([X|Xs],Relation_4) -->
   list_prev_foldadjl(Xs,X,Relation_4).

list_prev_foldadjl([],_,_) -->
   [].
list_prev_foldadjl([X1|Xs],X0,Relation_4) -->
   call(Relation_4,X0,X1),
   list_prev_foldadjl(Xs,X1,Relation_4).
```

---

#### Edit 2015-04-27

Here comes meta-predicate `splitlistIfAdj/3`, based on
`if_/3` which was proposed in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) 
on reification.

```
split_if_adj(P_3,As,Bss) :- splitlistIfAdj(P_3,As,Bss).

splitlistIfAdj(P_3,As,Bss) :- 
   list_split_(As,Bss,P_3).

list_split_([],[],_).
list_split_([X0|Xs],     [Cs|Bss],P_3) :-
   list_prev_split_(Xs,X0,Cs,Bss, P_3).

list_prev_split_([],     X, [X],[],_).
list_prev_split_([X1|Xs],X0,[X0|Cs],Bss,P_3) :-
   if_(call(P_3,X0,X1), 
       (Cs = [],  Bss = [Cs0|Bss0]),
       (Cs = Cs0, Bss = Bss0)),
   list_prev_split_(Xs,X1,Cs0,Bss0,P_3).
```

To show it in use let's define `dif/3` exactly the same way as `(=)/3` but with flipped truth-value:

```
dif(X, Y, R) :- X == Y,    !, R = false.
dif(X, Y, R) :- ?=(X, Y),  !, R = true. % syntactically different
dif(X, Y, R) :- X \= Y,    !, R = true. % semantically different
dif(X, Y, R) :- R == false, !, X = Y.
dif(X, X, false).
dif(X, Y, true) :-
   dif(X, Y).
```

Now we use them in tandem:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif,[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],Pss).
Pss = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]].      % succeeds deterministically
```

What if we generalize some list items? Do we get multiple answers with the right pending goals?

First, a small example:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif,[1,X,2],Pss).
X = 1,             Pss = [[1,1],[2]]  ;
X = 2,             Pss = [[1],[2,2]]  ;
dif(X,1),dif(X,2), Pss = [[1],[X],[2]].
```

A somewhat bigger example involving the two variables `X` and `Y`.

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(dif,[1,2,2,X,3,3,Y,4,4,4],Pss).
X = 2,             Y = 3,             Pss = [[1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]    ;
X = 2,             Y = 4,             Pss = [[1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[4,4,4,4]]    ;
X = 2,             dif(Y,3),dif(Y,4), Pss = [[1],[2,2,2],[3,3],[Y],[4,4,4]]  ;
X = Y,             Y = 3,             Pss = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4]]    ;
X = 3,             Y = 4,             Pss = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]    ;
X = 3,             dif(Y,3),dif(Y,4), Pss = [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[Y],[4,4,4]]  ;
dif(X,2),dif(X,3), Y = 3,             Pss = [[1],[2,2],[X],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]  ;
dif(X,2),dif(X,3), Y = 4,             Pss = [[1],[2,2],[X],[3,3],[4,4,4,4]]  ;
dif(X,2),dif(X,3), dif(Y,3),dif(Y,4), Pss = [[1],[2,2],[X],[3,3],[Y],[4,4,4]].
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-05

Here's `tpartition/4`:

```
tpartition(P_2,List,Ts,Fs) :- tpartition_ts_fs_(List,Ts,Fs,P_2).

tpartition_ts_fs_([],[],[],_).
tpartition_ts_fs_([X|Xs0],Ts,Fs,P_2) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), (Ts = [X|Ts0], Fs = Fs0),
                    (Ts = Ts0,     Fs = [X|Fs0])),
   tpartition_ts_fs_(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,P_2).
```

Sample use:

```
?- tpartition(=(0), [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,0,1], Ts, Fs).
Ts = [0, 0, 0],
Fs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1].
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-15

On and on, ... here's `splitlistIf/3`:

```
split_if(P_2,As,Bss) :- splitlistIf(P_2,As,Bss).

splitlistIf(P_2,As,Bss) :-
   list_pred_split(As,P_2,Bss).

list_pred_split([],_,[]).
list_pred_split([X|Xs],P_2,Bss) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), list_pred_split(Xs,P_2,Bss),
                    (Bss = [[X|Ys]|Bss0], list_pred_open_split(Xs,P_2,Ys,Bss0))).

list_pred_open_split([],_,[],[]).
list_pred_open_split([X|Xs],P_2,Ys,Bss) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), (Ys = [],      list_pred_split(Xs,P_2,Bss)),
                    (Ys = [X|Ys0], list_pred_open_split(Xs,P_2,Ys0,Bss))).
```

Let's use it:

```
?- splitlistIf(=(x),[x,1,2,x,1,2,3,x,1,4,x,x,x,x,1,x,2,x,x,1],Xs).
Xs = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4], [1], [2], [1]].
```

Comment: Many thanks for this list of useful meta-predicates, +1! For this concrete question, I am only searching for a single name, so I suppose you suggest `mapadj/2`? This would certainly work. I see two still open issues: (a) Is `mapadj/2` ever useful with any relations other than "orderings"? And (b) `mapadj/2` does not name an actual arising structure like `connex/2` which would make a lot of sense in the context of CLP(FD) constraints, so in this sense the predicate (name) is *too* general.

Answer (score 3):

Quite in the same vein as `mapadj/4` presented in an earlier answer... **maybe the name is better.**

```
forallAdj(P_2,Xs) :-
   list_forallAdj(Xs,P_2).

list_forallAdj([],_).
list_forallAdj([X|Xs],P_2) :-
   list_forallAdj_prev(Xs,P_2,X).

list_forallAdj_prev([],_,_).
list_forallAdj_prev([X1|Xs],P_2,X0) :-
   call(P_2,X0,X1),
   list_forallAdj_prev(Xs,P_2,X1).
```

Sample use:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

?- Ls = [0,_,_,_,_,_], forallAdj(\X0^X1^(X0 + 1 #= X1), Ls).
Ls = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

Where could that take us?

- `forallAdj` => `existAdj`
- maybe variants with index (`forallAdjI`, `existAdjI`) like in [Collections.List Module (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353738.aspx)
- `findfirstAdj`/`pickfirstAdj` also like F# `find`/`pick`

Comment: Are there no typeclasses in F#? Requirements for many functions seem very *ad hoc* - just the existence of some static members. So there seems to be a global semantic scope for static members. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034802/how-would-i-translate-a-haskell-type-class-into-f)

Comment: I wish we could have something along type classes - at least on a conceptual level.