# Prolog: Split list at integer in list of lists

Tags: list, recursion, split, prolog

I would like to split a list of words separated through integers into a list of lists.

Sample query and expected result:

```
?- separatewords([h,e,l,l,o,1,o,v,e,r,3,t,h,e,r,e], X).
X = [[h,e,l,l,o],[o,v,e,r],[t,h,e,r,e]].
```

The following things I already achieved:
Splitting the list into one list before the first integer and one after the first integer:

Sample query with result:

```
?- take1word([h,e,l,l,o,1,o,v,e,r,3,t,h,e,r,e], X, Y).
X = [h,e,l,l,o], Y = [o,v,e,r,3,t,h,e,r,e].                 % OK
```

My code:

```
 take1word([H|T],[],T) :-
    integer(H).
 take1word([H|T],[H|Hs],Y) :-
    (  float(H), take1word(T,Hs,Y)
    ;  atom(H), take1word(T,Hs,Y)
    ).
```

For separating words my code is the following:

```
 separatewords([],[]).
 separatewords([H|T],L) :-  separatewords(T,[take1word([H|T],)|L]).
```

It only give me `false` as a result, but I don't know, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with `take1word/3`: it will take a word if there is an integer in the list, but it will not take the last word. You need to add another base clause to it:

```
take1word([], [], []).
take1word([H|T],[],T) :- integer(H).
take1word([H|T],[H|Hs],Y) :- float(H), take1word(T,Hs,Y); atom(H), take1word(T,Hs,Y).
```

Now your `separatewords/2` will work:

```
separatewords([],[]).
separatewords(L, [W|T]) :- take1word(L,W,R), separatewords(R,T).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/igDOL4)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could proceed in a logically-pure fashion.

Use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`splitlistIf/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) in tandem with the reified type test predicate `integer_t/2`!

```
integer_t(X,Truth) :- integer(X), !, Truth = true.
integer_t(X,Truth) :- nonvar(X),  !, Truth = false.
integer_t(X,true)  :- freeze(X,  integer(X)).
integer_t(X,false) :- freeze(X,\+integer(X)).
```

Let's see them both in action!

```
?- Xs=[ h,e,l,l,o,1,o,v,e,r,3,t,h,e,r,e ], splitlistIf(integer_truth,Xs,Yss).
Xs  = [ h,e,l,l,o,1,o,v,e,r,3,t,h,e,r,e ],
Yss = [[h,e,l,l,o],[o,v,e,r],[t,h,e,r,e]]. % succeeds deterministically
```

As the implementation is monotone, it can be safely used when we work with non-ground terms.

Consider the following two logically equivalent queries: Procedurally, they differ regarding the instantiation of items in `Xs` at the time the goal `splitListIf(integer_t,Xs,Yss)` is proven.

```
?- Xs = [_,_,_,_,_], Xs = [a,b,0,b,a], splitlistIf(integer_t,Xs,Yss).
Xs = [a,b,0,b,a], Yss = [[a,b],[b,a]].     % succeeds deterministically

?- Xs = [_,_,_,_,_], splitlistIf(integer_t,Xs,Yss), Xs = [a,b,0,b,a].
  Xs = [a,b,0,b,a], Yss = [[a,b],[b,a]]    % succeeds leaving behind choicepoint
; false.
```

The implementation is smart enough to leave behind choicepoint(s) only when necessary.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306453/safer-type-tests-in-prolog) to the name finding.

Comment: CamelCase is not very Prolog-ish. `int` is not a type. `integer_truth/2`.  Referring to state of instantiation (`Nonvar`) is not necessary: An implementation without constraints would quite correctly produce an instantiation error in stead.

Comment: The ground case is the thing to look at, first. What else apart from integers can be even? Natural numbers, but they are not an explicit type. And as domain the are `not_less_than_zero`. So `even_truth` looks good enough to me. On the other hand, most of your definitions accept expressions like `0+0`

Comment: Good point! What could / should I do about that? Type tests + exceptions? Or rather use the `clpfd_monotonic` flag in combination with  `(?)/1` ?