# Split a list in separate lists

Tags: prolog

I have to define some more constraints for my list.

I want to split my list is separate lists.

Example:

```
List=[[1,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[3,1],[_,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]]
```

I need three Lists which i get from the main list:

```
[[_,0],[_,0],[_,0]] and [[_,0]] and [[2,0],[4,0]]
```

SO I always need a group of lists between a term with [X,1].

It would be great if u could give me a tip. Don’t want the solution, only a tip how to solve this.

Jörg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation tries to preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) without restricting the list items to be `[_,_]`, like
[@false's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28396804/4609915) does.
I can see that imposing above restriction *does* make a lot of sense... still I would like to lift it---and attack the more general problem.

The following is based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), [`splitlistIf/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and reified predicate, `marker_truth/2`.
`marker_truth(M,T)`  reifies the "marker"-ness of `M` into the truth value `T` (`true` or `false`).

```
is_marker([_,1]).                      % non-reified

marker_truth([_,1],true).              % reified: variant #1
marker_truth(Xs,false) :-
   dif(Xs,[_,1]).
```

Easy enough! Let's try `splitlistIf/3` and `marker_truth/2` together in a query:

```
?- Ls=[[1,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[3,1],[_,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]], 
   splitlistIf(marker_truth,Ls,Pss).
Ls  = [[1,1],[_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0],[3,1],[_D,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]],
Pss = [     [[_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0]],    [[_D,0]],    [[2,0],[4,0]]] ? ; % OK
Ls  = [[1,1],[_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0],[3,1],[_D,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]],
Pss = [     [[_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0]],    [[_D,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]]],
prolog:dif([9,1],[_E,1])                                           ? ; % BAD
%% query aborted (6 other BAD answers omitted)
```

**D'oh!**

The second answer shown above is certainly **not** what we wanted. 
Clearly, `splitlistIf/3` *should* have split `Ls` at that point, 
as the goal `is_marker([9,1])` succeeds. It didn't. Instead, we got an answer with a frozen `dif/2` goal that will *never* be woken up, because it is waiting for the instantiation of the anonymous variable `_E`.

Guess who's to blame! The second clause of `marker_truth/2`:

```
marker_truth(Xs,false) :- dif(Xs,[_,1]).       % BAD
```

What can we do about it? Use our own inequality predicate that doesn't freeze on a variable which will never be instantiated:

```
marker_truth(Xs,Truth) :-                      % variant #2
   freeze(Xs, marker_truth__1(Xs,Truth)).

marker_truth__1(Xs,Truth) :-
   (  Xs = [_|Xs0]
   -> freeze(Xs0, marker_truth__2(Xs0,Truth))
   ;  Truth = false
   ).

marker_truth__2(Xs,Truth) :-
   (  Xs = [X|Xs0]
   -> when((nonvar(X);nonvar(Xs0)), marker_truth__3(X,Xs0,Truth))
   ;  Truth = false
   ).

marker_truth__3(X,Xs0,Truth) :- % X or Xs0 have become nonvar
   (  nonvar(X)
   -> (  X == 1 
      -> freeze(Xs0,(Xs0 == [] -> Truth = true ; Truth = false))
      ;  Truth = false
      )
   ;  Xs0 == []
   -> freeze(X,(X == 1 -> Truth = true ; Truth = false))
   ;  Truth = false
   ).
```

All this code, for expressing the safe logical negation of `is_marker([_,1])`? *UGLY!*

Let's see if it (at least) helped above query (the one which gave so many useless answers)!

```
?- Ls=[[1,1],[_,0],[_,0],[_,0],[3,1],[_,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]],
   splitlistIf(marker_truth,Ls,Pss).
Ls  = [[1,1],[_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0],[3,1],[_D,0],[9,1],[2,0],[4,0]],
Pss = [[     [_A,0],[_B,0],[_C,0]],    [[_D,0]],    [[2,0],[4,0]]] ? ;
no
```

It works! When considering the coding effort required, however, it is clear that either a code generation scheme or a
variant of `dif/2` (which shows above behaviour) will have to be devised.

---

#### Edit 2015-05-25

Above implementation `marker_truth/2` *somewhat* works, but leaves a lot to be desired. Consider:

```
?- marker_truth(M,Truth).                   % most general use
freeze(M, marker_truth__1(M, Truth)).
```

This answer is not what we would like to get. To see why not, let's look  at the answers of a comparable use of [`integer_truth/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30291357/4609915):

```
?- integer_truth(I,Truth).                  % most general use
Truth = true,  freeze(I, integer(I)) ;
Truth = false, freeze(I, \+integer(I)).
```

Two answers in the most general case---**that's** how a reified predicate should behave like!

Let's recode `marker_truth/2` accordingly:

```
marker_truth(Xs,Truth) :- subsumes_term([_,1],Xs), !, Truth = true.
marker_truth(Xs,Truth) :- Xs \= [_,1],             !, Truth = false.
marker_truth([_,1],true).
marker_truth(Xs   ,false) :- nonMarker__1(Xs).

nonMarker__1(T) :- var(T),      !, freeze(T,nonMarker__1(T)).
nonMarker__1(T) :- T = [_|Arg], !, nonMarker__2(Arg).
nonMarker__1(_).

nonMarker__2(T) :- var(T),    !, freeze(T,nonMarker__2(T)).
nonMarker__2(T) :- T = [_|_], !, dif(T,[1]).
nonMarker__2(_).
```

Let's re-run above query with the new implementation of `marker_truth/2`:

```
?- marker_truth(M,Truth).                   % most general use
Truth = true,  M = [_A,1] ;
Truth = false, freeze(M, nonMarker__1(M)).
```

Comment: Instead of showing a wall of answer substitutions, why not make queries that detect the incorrect answer substitutions? This would reduce the need for highlighting.

Comment: After "OMG": Why don't you give concrete queries, why you are unhappy with the first version? I don't think that it is easy to follow you without.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you mean by a "group of lists". In your example you start with `[1,1]` which fits your criterion of `[_,1]`. So shouldn't there be an empty list in the beginning? Or maybe you meant that it all starts with such a marker?
And what if there are further markers around?

First you need to define the criterion for a marker element. This for both cases: When it applies and when it does not apply and thus this is an element in between.

```
marker([_,1]).

nonmarker([_,C]) :-
   dif(1, C).
```

Note that with these predicates we imply that every element *has* to be `[_,_]`. You did not state it, but it does make sense.

```
split(Xs, As, Bs, Cs) :-
   phrase(three_seqs(As, Bs, Cs), Xs).

marker -->
   [E],
   {marker(E)}.

three_seqs(As, Bs, Cs) -->
   marker,
   all_seq(nonmarker, As),
   marker,
   all_seq(nonmarker, Bs),
   marker,
   all_seq(nonmarker, Cs).
```

For a definition of `all_seq//2` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24106828/772868)

In place of `marker`, one could write `all_seq(marker,[_])`

Comment: thank u very much fo the answer... yaer it start with such a marker and ends at such a marker.. and the predicate IS [_,_].  I will try to understand your answer. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use a predicate like `append/3`. For example, to split a list on the first occurence of the atom `x` in it, you would say:

```
?- L =  [a,b,c,d,x,e,f,g,x,h,i,j], once(append(Before, [x|After], L)).
L = [a, b, c, d, x, e, f, g, x|...],
Before = [a, b, c, d],
After = [e, f, g, x, h, i, j].
```

As @false has pointed out, putting an extra requirement might change your result, but this is what is nice about using `append/3`:

"Split the list on `x` so that the second part starts with `h`:

```
?- L =  [a,b,c,d,x,e,f,g,x,h,i,j], After = [h|_], append(Before, [x|After], L).
L = [a, b, c, d, x, e, f, g, x|...],
After = [h, i, j],
Before = [a, b, c, d, x, e, f, g].
```

This is just the tip.

Comment: Downside: This approach is not steadfast. If `Before` or `After ` is (partially) given, the result might be a different one.

Comment: .. like `After = [h|_]`

Comment: @false Yes, but how is that a problem? Saying that `After` must begin with something (in your example, `After = [h|_]`, just puts another requirement, and the solution is "correct", as in, you get what you ask for.

Comment: The problem is that `After = [h|_], g(After)` and `g(After), After = [h|_]` mean entirely different things. Thus you have to take into account all details of execution instead of simply the set of ground solutions. More complexity means less chance to get it right.

Comment: @fase Yes, because of `once/1`. If it is not there, it works as expected.

Comment: You *need* `once/1` to catch exactly the first occurrence, without it you would describe all occurences.

Comment: @false Yes, I realize that. I am not claiming that this is a perfect solution. But saying that changing the order of the goals leads to "entirely different things" is a slight exaggeration which might lead to confusion.

Comment: The situation is pretty much the same when you mix these goals with constraints where you have much less control of what is instantiated when.

Comment: @false Getting philosophical again, but many (most) questions here on SO "how do I do X" are best answered with "don't do it" (this includes my questions, too). This question is a perfect example. I know that your answer is good, I know that my answer is not completely useless, and understand its limitations. I don't even know why I keep answering misguided questions with misguided answers.

Comment: As long as you do not explicitly shield your solution against those uses that you do not cover, your program must be considered incorrect.

Comment: @false This is not different from saying "as long as you don't understand what you are doing, all your programs must be incorrect", which for most of us mortals is actually true.

Comment: I cannot agree with you.

Comment: @false I would have been shocked if you did :) in my defense, I do read carefully what you write and try to learn.