# Extracting sequences (Lists) Prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a list eg `[1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4]` how would I extract the sequences within the list?

A sequence is defined as an ordered list (Normally I would say n-tuple but I have been told in prolog a tuple is referred to as a sequence). So we want to cut the list at the point where the next element is smaller than the previous one.

So for the list `[1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4]` it should return:

`[ [1,2,3,7], [2,5,8,9], [3,4] ]` `%ie we have cut the list at position 4 & 8.`

For this exercise you CANNOT use the construct `;` or `->`

Many thanks in advance!

---

**EXAMPLE RESULTS**:

eg1.

```
?-function([1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4],X): %so we cut the list at position 4 & 9
```

`X = [ [1,2,3,7], [2,5,8,9], [3,4] ]`.

eg2.

```
?-function([1,2,3,2,2,3,4,3],X): %so we cut the list at position 3,4 & 8

X = [ [1,2,3], [2], [2,3,4], [3] ].
```

---

Hopefully that helps clarify the problem. If you need further clarification just let me know! Thanks again in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Well initially I thought just split it when u find: Element_i+1<Element_i. But that wont work if you have duplicated numbers in the list. I attempted using maplist/3 (i used 2x the same lists where i just added a 0 to beginning of one and to the end of the other) to "map" all the elements where X<Y to return all the index's where the condition is false then just recursively extract it using (see link below). But now that it doesnt work I have no idea what to do/confusing myself more......http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/problemas-prolog/p18.prolog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's break it down conceptually. The predicate `list_ascending_rest/3` defines a relation between a list `Xs`, the left-most ascending sublist of maximum length `Ys`, and the remaining items `Rest`. We will use it like in the following query:

```
?- Xs = [1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4], list_ascending_rest(Xs,Ys,Rest).
Ys   = [1,2,3,7],
Rest = [2,5,8,9,3,4] ;
false.
```

The straight-forward predicate definition goes like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_ascending_rest([],[],[]).
list_ascending_rest([A],[A],[]).
list_ascending_rest([A1,A2|As], [A1], [A2|As]) :-
    A1 #>= A2.
list_ascending_rest([A1,A2|As], [A1|Bs], Cs) :-
    A1 #< A2,
    list_ascending_rest([A2|As], Bs,Cs).
```

Then, let's implement predicate `list_ascendingParts/2`. This predicate repeatedly uses `list_ascending_rest/3` for each part until nothing is left.

```
list_ascendingParts([],[]).
list_ascendingParts([A|As],[Bs|Bss]) :-
    list_ascending_rest([A|As],Bs,As0),
    list_ascendingParts(As0,Bss).
```

Example queries:

```
?- list_ascendingParts([1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4],Xs).
Xs = [[1,2,3,7], [2,5,8,9], [3,4]] ;
false.

?-  list_ascendingParts([1,2,3,2,2,3,4,3],Xs).
Xs = [[1,2,3], [2], [2,3,4], [3]] ;
false.
```

---

#### Edit 2015/04/05

What if the ascending parts are known but the list is unknown? Let's find  out:

```
?- list_ascendingParts(Ls, [[3,4,5],[4],[2,7],[5,6],[6,8],[3]]).
Ls = [3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3] ? ;
no
```

And let's not forget about the most general query using `list_ascendingParts/2`:

```
?- assert(clpfd:full_answer).
yes

?- list_ascendingParts(Ls, Ps).
Ls = [],      Ps = []                                                   ? ;
Ls = [_A],    Ps = [[_A]]                                               ? ;
Ls = [_A,_B], Ps = [[_A],[_B]], _B#=<_A, _B in inf..sup, _A in inf..sup ? ...
```

---

#### Edit 2015-04-27

Room for improvement? Yes, *definitely*!

By using the meta-predicate [`splitlistIfAdj/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) one can "succeed deterministically"  *and* "use non-determinism when required", depending on the situation.

`splitlistIfAdj/3` is based on `if_/3` as proposed by @false in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) answer. So the predicate passed to it has to obey the same convention as `(=)/3` and `memberd_truth/3`.

So let's define `(#>)/3` and `(#>=)/3`:

```
#>=(X,Y,Truth) :- X #>= Y #<==> B, =(B,1,Truth).
#>( X,Y,Truth) :- X #>  Y #<==> B, =(B,1,Truth).
```

Let's re-ask above queries, using `splitlistIfAdj(#>=)`
instead of `list_ascendingParts`:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>=,[1,2,3,7,2,5,8,9,3,4],Pss).
Pss = [[1,2,3,7],[2,5,8,9],[3,4]].        % succeeds deterministically
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>=,[1,2,3,2,2,3,4,3],Pss).
Pss = [[1,2,3],[2],[2,3,4],[3]].          % succeeds deterministically

?- splitlistIfAdj(#>=,Ls,[[3,4,5],[4],[2,7],[5,6],[6,8],[3]]).
Ls = [3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3] ;            % works the other way round, too
false.                                    % universally terminates
```

Last, the most general query. I wonder what the answers look like:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>=,Ls,Pss).
Ls = Pss,              Pss = [] ;
Ls = [_G28],           Pss = [[_G28]] ;
Ls = [_G84,_G87],      Pss = [[_G84],[_G87]],        _G84#>=_G87 ;
Ls = [_G45,_G48,_G41], Pss = [[_G45],[_G48],[_G41]], _G45#>=_G48, _G48#>=_G41 
% and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

`maplist/3` as suggested in the comment won't help you here because `maplist/3` is good at taking a list and mapping each element into a same-size collection of something else, or establishing a relation evenly across all of the individual elements. In this problem, you are trying to gather contiguous sublists that have certain properties.

Here's a DCG solution. The idea here is to examine the list as a series of increasing sequences where, at the boundary between them, the last element of the prior sequence is less than or equal to the first element of the following sequence (as the problem statement basically indicates).

```
% A set of sequences is an increasing sequence ending in X
%    followed by a set of sequences that starts with a value =< X
sequences([S|[[Y|T]|L]]) --> inc_seq(S, X), sequences([[Y|T]|L]), { X >= Y }.
sequences([S]) --> inc_seq(S, _).
sequences([]) --> [].

% An increasing sequence, where M is the maximum value
inc_seq([X,Y|T], M) --> [X], inc_seq([Y|T], M), { X < Y }.
inc_seq([X], X) --> [X].

partition(L, R) :- phrase(sequences(R), L).

| ?- partition([1,2,3,4,2,3,8,7], R).

R = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,8],[7]] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?-  partition([1,2,3,2,2,3,4,3],X).

X = [[1,2,3],[2],[2,3,4],[3]] ? ;

(1 ms) no
```

The only reason for the rule `sequences([]) --> [].` is if you want `partition([], [])` to be true. Otherwise, the rule isn't required.