# prolog- break a list

Tags: list, prolog

The example is like this

```
?- runs([3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3], RunList).
RunList = [[3, 4, 5], [4], [2, 7], [5, 6, 6, 8], [3]]
```

The list need to be broken in to a number of non-decreasing sequence of consecutive numbers. My code is:

```
next([],0).
next([H|_],R):-
    R is H.

runs1([],[]).
runs1([H|T],R):-
    runs1(T,R1),
    next(T,X),
    H=<X,
    R = [H|R1].
runs1([H|T],R):-
    runs1(T,R1),
    next(T,X),
    H>X,
    R = [[H]|R1].
```

I tried lots of methods, but still do not know how to write it...

Hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting sequences (Lists) Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405498/extracting-sequences-lists-prolog)

Answer (score 1):

For a **logically pure** and **monotone** implementation look at
[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426545/4609915) to related question "[Extracting sequences (Lists) Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405498/extracting-sequences-lists-prolog)".

I present the meta-predicate `splitlistIfAdj/3` which is based on `if_/3` as proposed by @false in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915). 
`splitlistIfAdj/3` ensures logical soundness while remaining deterministic when possible.

The predicate passed to `splitlistIfAdj/3` has to obey the same convention as `(=)/3` and `memberd_truth/3`.
For your case we need a definition of `(#>)/3`:

```
#>(X,Y,Truth) :- X #> Y #<==> B, =(B,1,Truth).
```

Let's use `splitlistIfAdj/3` and `(#>)/3` in the example you gave:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>,[3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3],Pss).
Pss = [[3,4,5],[4],[2,7],[5,6,6,8],[3]].          % succeeds deterministically
```

Now let's ask a more general query:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>,[A,B],Pss).
Pss = [[A],[B]], A#>=_X,        B+1#=_X ;
Pss = [[A,B]],   A#>=_Y#<==>_Z, B+1#=_Y, _Z in 0..1, dif(_Z,1).
```

Last, let's run the query that @lurker suggested in his comment to @rrrfer's answer:

```
?- splitlistIfAdj(#>, Ls, [[3,4,5],[4],[2,7],[5,6,6,8],[3]]).
Ls = [3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3] ;
false.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
runs([], []):-!.
runs([H|T], S):-
  runs(T, TS),
  ins(H, TS, S).

ins(E, [], [[E]]):-!.
ins(E, [[H|T]|TL], [[E, H|T]|TL]):-
  H >= E, !.
ins(E, TL, [[E]|TL]).
```

Comment: It would be good to explain to the OP why theirs failed and your solution works. Also, although this works one direction (as a *function*), it doesn't define a *relation*, so `runs(L, [[3, 4, 5], [4], [2, 7], [5, 6, 6, 8], [3]]).` fails rather than yielding, `L = [3,4,5,4,2,7,5,6,6,8,3]`.

Comment: How i can resolve this problem? - do you have any example of this technics - it's so interesting for me

Comment: See the link I provided in the comment to the original question for a couple of examples.