# Prolog code to split parts of a list into consecutive even and odd parts

Tags: prolog

I've been given the following question:

Any list of integers can (uniquely) be broken into "parity runs" where each run is a (maximal) sequence of consecutive even or odd numbers within the original list. For example, the list
`List = [8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9]`
can be broken into `[8, 0, 4]`, `[3, 7]`, `[2]` and `[-1, 9, 9]`
Write a predicate `paruns(List, RunList)` that converts a list of numbers into the corresponding list of parity runs. For example:

```
?- paruns([8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9], RunList).
RunList = [[8, 0, 4], [3, 7], [2], [-1, 9, 9]]
```

Here was the code which I tried and it seems to work with the above sample case, thanks to one suggestion, but I've got an issue where when I run `paruns([8,0,4], RunList).` it prints `RunList = [[8,0,4],[]]`. Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

```
paruns([],[]).
paruns([Head | Tail], [E, O | S]) :-
   even([Head | Tail], E, Last),
   odd(Last, O, Last1),
   paruns(Last1, S).

even([Head | Tail], [], [Head | Tail]) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 1.
even([Head | Tail], [Head | L], Last) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 0,
   even(Tail, L, Last).
even([],[],[]).

odd([Head | Tail], [], [Head, Tail]) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 0.
odd([Head | Tail], [Head | L], Last) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 1,
   odd(Tail, L, Last).
odd([],[],[]).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have just a typo, in the first odd/3 clause. With the following code

```
paruns([],[]).
paruns([Head | Tail], [E, O | S]) :-
   even([Head | Tail], E, Last),
   odd(Last, O, Last1),
   paruns(Last1, S).

even([Head | Tail], [], [Head | Tail]) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 1.
even([Head | Tail], [Head | L], Last) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 0,
   even(Tail, L, Last).
even([],[],[]).

odd([Head | Tail], [], [Head | Tail]) :-  % corrected
   Head mod 2 =:= 0.
odd([Head | Tail], [Head | L], Last) :-
   Head mod 2 =:= 1,
   odd(Tail, L, Last).
odd([],[],[]).
```

I get

```
?- paruns([8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9], RunList).
RunList = [[8, 0, 4], [3, 7], [2], [-1, 9, 9]]
```

*edit*

A possibility to discard empty sequences (should occurs only at first or last position, I think... so maybe a better approach would be to sanitize the outcome for these cases):

```
paruns([],[]).
%paruns([Head | Tail], [E, O | S]) :-
paruns([Head | Tail], R) :-
   even([Head | Tail], E, Last),
   odd(Last, O, Last1),
    (E=[] -> R=[O|S] ; O=[] -> R=[E|S] ; R=[E,O|S]),
   paruns(Last1, S).
```

Comment: Thanks so much I don't know how I didn't see that, only now I have one small other question if you could help. When I run it with the above example it gets perfect output, however with 'paruns([8,0,4], RunList).' it prints RunList = [[8,0,4],[]]. Any suggestions on how to fix this?? Thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry, the easier 'solution' leads to ugly code, anyway, see my edit...

Answer (score 4):

A major attraction of Prolog is its **relational nature**. This means that we can often use a Prolog predicate in *several directions*, if only we stick to sufficiently general primitives.

In this concrete case, since you are reasoning over **integers**, I highly recommend you use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** to benefit from this generality. Please see [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information about this important declarative feature.

In addition, since you are describing a *list*, consider using **DCG notation** ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)).

Here is a *relational* solution for your task:

```
parity_runs([], [])     --> [].
parity_runs([E|Es], Os) --> [E], { E mod 2 #= 0 }, parity_runs(Es, Os).
parity_runs(Es, [O|Os]) --> [O], { O mod 2 #= 1 }, parity_runs(Es, Os).
```

We can use it for the test case you posted, where the list is specified:

```
?- phrase(parity_runs(Es, Os), [8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9]).
Es = [8, 0, 4, 2],
Os = [3, 7, -1, 9, 9] ;
false.
```

Moreover, we can also use it in *other* directions. For example, suppose that the *runs* are known, but the list isn't:

```
?- phrase(parity_runs([2,4], [1,3]), Ls).
Ls = [2, 4, 1, 3] ;
Ls = [2, 1, 4, 3] ;
Ls = [2, 1, 3, 4] ;
Ls = [1, 2, 4, 3] ;
Ls = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
Ls = [1, 3, 2, 4] ;
false.
```

Moreover, we can also post the **most general query**, where nothing is known:

```
?- phrase(parity_runs(Es, Os), Ls).
Es = Os, Os = Ls, Ls = [] ;
Es = Ls, Ls = [_2012],
Os = [],
_2012 mod 2#=0 ;
Es = Ls, Ls = [_256, _258],
Os = [],
_256 mod 2#=0,
_258 mod 2#=0 ;
Es = Ls, Ls = [_826, _832, _838],
Os = [],
_826 mod 2#=0,
_832 mod 2#=0,
_838 mod 2#=0 ;
etc.
```

To *fairly* enumerate answers, we can use **iterative deepening**:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(parity_runs(Es, Os), Ls).
Ls = Es, Es = Os, Os = [] ;
Ls = Es, Es = [_168],
Os = [],
_168 mod 2#=0 ;
Ls = Os, Os = [_550],
Es = [],
_550 mod 2#=1 ;
Ls = Es, Es = [_770, _776],
Os = [],
_770 mod 2#=0,
_776 mod 2#=0 ;
Ls = [_770, _776],
Es = [_770],
Os = [_776],
_770 mod 2#=0,
_776 mod 2#=1 ;
etc.
```

Comment: thanks for all the advice, i actually went out and learnt about clpfd today and i can see its got a lot of use! i've actually just started prolog and coming from C its quite a difference but your write up was very educative! thanks again! :)

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**
Find the "right peg" for the "hole" in [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `split_if_adj/3` and you're done!

---

This answer is based upon:

- [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) (Constraint Logic Programming over Finite Domains),

  ```
  :- use_module(library(clpfd)).
  ```
- [reified term equality `(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915),

  ```
  :- use_module(library(reif)).
  ```
- [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`split_if_adj/3` (defined in a previous answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915),
- and the reified condition predicate `dif_parity_t/3`:

  ```
  dif_parity_t(X, Y, T) :-
     (X+Y) mod 2 #= M,
     =(M,1,T).                  % reified term equality
  ```

So, basically, we're delegating the cumbersome and sometimes tricky task of handling lists recursively to a higher-order predicate which we customize appropriately.

Sample query:

```
?- split_if_adj(dif_parity_t, [8,0,4,3,7,2,-1,9,9], Rss).
Rss = [[8,0,4],[3,7],[2],[-1,9,9]].
```

Note that above query succeeds deterministically.