# Prolog unpacking lists predicate

Tags: prolog

I tried to create something what would work like this:

```
?- unpacking([[1], [1,2], [3]], Lst1, NewLst).
NewLst=[1,3]
```

I wrote it like this:

```
unpacking([], Lst1, Lst1).
unpacking([[H]|T], Lst1, NewLst):-
    append([H], Lst2),
    unpacking(T, Lst2, NewLst).
unpacking([_|T], Lst1, NewLst):-
    unpacking(T, Lst1, NewLst).
```

and I know that I am doing something wrong. I am starting in Prolog so, need to learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: What do you expect for `[[],[1],[2]]`?

Comment: What does this do? What is it supposed to do? What is your problem?...

Comment: @false actually never thought about that input :) because im working with lists that normally have something inside.

Comment: @Boris what this does is unpacks a list into another list, but only keep the one-elements list, so instead of a list of lists is a list with non-list elements, which only keeps the one-elements list, kinda confusing i see.

Comment: But why do you have three arguments? Two arguments should be enough I have the feeling....

Comment: @Bl4ckCoding: You do not "keep the one-elements list" - rather you keep the elements of one-element lists.

Comment: @false ok yeh, my english is not that good, but yeh thats it!

Comment: unpack(Xs,Ys) is easiest described as: "Ys is the concatenation of all singleton lists in Xs (in the order they appear in Xs)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
unpacking([], []).
unpacking([[E]|T], [E|L]) :-
   unpacking(T, L).
unpacking([[]|T], L) :-
   unpacking(T, L).
unpacking([[_,_|_]|T], L) :-
   unpacking(T, L).
```

There are more concise ways to write this - and more efficient, too.

Comment: yep, it works man thanks! But could you explain the code a little bit?

Comment: It's a pattern matching on the head of the list - the element is either ```[E]``` or ```[]``` or ```[ _, _ |_ ]```. In all cases, you obtain the remaining elements ```L``` by a recursion on the tail ```T```. In the one-element case, ```E``` is prepended to ```L``` whereas in the other cases, ```L``` by itself suffices.

Comment: unpacking([[_,_|_]|T, L) is a typo I think.

Comment: Thx! Where is your answer?

Answer (score 6):

What about this :

```
%?-unpacking([[a,b,c],[a],[b],[c,d]],Items).
unpacking(Lists,Items):-
 my_tpartition(length_t(1),Lists,Items,Falses).

my_tpartition(P_2,List,Ts,Fs) :- my_tpartition_ts_fs_(List,Ts,Fs,P_2).

my_tpartition_ts_fs_([],[],[],_).
my_tpartition_ts_fs_([X|Xs0],Ts,Fs,P_2) :-
 if_(call(P_2,X), (X=[NX],Ts = [NX|Ts0], Fs = Fs0),
                (Ts = Ts0,     Fs = [X|Fs0])),
my_tpartition_ts_fs_(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,P_2).

length_t(X,Y,T):-
 length(Y,L1),
 =(X,L1,T).
```

This is based on [Most general higher-order constraint describing a sequence of integers ordered with respect to a relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990728/most-general-higher-order-constraint-describing-a-sequence-of-integers-ordered-w/29867514#29867514)

*** Update***

You could change to

```
length_t(X,Y,T):-
 L1 #=< X,
 fd_length(Y,L1),
 =(X,L1,T),!.

length_t(_X,_Y,false).

fd_length(L, N) :-
 N #>= 0,
 fd_length(L, N, 0).

fd_length([], N, N0) :-
 N #= N0.
fd_length([_|L], N, N0) :-
 N1 is N0+1,
 N #>= N1,
 fd_length(L, N, N1).
```

giving:

```
?-unpacking([[1],[2,3],[4],[_,_|_]],U).
U= [1,4].
```

but:

```
?-unpacking([X],Xs).
X = Xs, Xs = [].
```

Comment: The name tpartition is a bit misleading, for partitioning is typically  x ->  [x] -> [x] -> [x]

Comment: What do you suggest? how about rel_list_fillers_segments?

Comment: partition'n concat a Haskeller would say.

Comment: I like the idea behind this proposal very much, +s(0) for that. Unfortunately, due to the use of length/2, the query `?- unpacking([[1],[2,3],[4],[_,_|_]],U).` loops, yielding the solution `U = [1, 4]` over and over again. The accepted version, in comparison, is leaving an unnecessary choice point after yielding the only solution but terminates after hitting `;`.

Comment: but with the 4th item in the list of the first argument you asking for infinite solutions I think... so it should not terminate?

Comment: btw I think the joke should be s(X) not +s(0) as we dealing with nice peano arithmetic!

Comment: Yes, exactly. No matter what you substitute for the underscores in  `[_,_|_]` it certainly can't become a list with a single element. Hence it's not in the list anyway and it's pointless to iterate possibilities. However, I was thinking along the same lines and couldn't come up with a deterministic solution that terminates for that case so far. Concerning the nice peano arithmetic I submit and regret, please feel s(X)'ed instead ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Based on [@coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6671342/coder)'s solution, I made my own attempt using `if_` and DCGs:

```
one_element_([], true).
one_element_([_|_],false).

one_element([], false).
one_element([_|Xs], T) :-
    one_element_(Xs, T).

f([]) -->
    [].
f([X|Xs]) -->
    { if_(one_element(X), Y=X, Y=[]) },
    Y,
    f(Xs).

unpack(Xs,Ys) :-
    phrase(f(Xs),Ys).
```

I only tried for about 30s, but the queries:

```
?- Xs = [[] | Xs], unpack(Xs,Ys).
?- Xs = [[_] | Xs], unpack(Xs,Ys).
?- Xs = [[_, _ | _] | Xs], unpack(Xs,Ys).
```

didn't stop with a stack overflow. In my opinion, the critical one should be the last query, but apparently, SWI Prolog manages to optimize:

```
?- L = [_,_|_], one_element(L,T).
L = [_3162, _3168|_3170],
T = false.
```

**Edit**: I improved the solution and gave it a shot with argument indexing. According to the [SWI Manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jitindex), indexing happens if there is exactly a case distinction between the empty list `[]` and the non-empty list `[_|_]`. I rewrote `one_element` such that it does exactly that and repeated the trick with the auxiliary predicate `one_element_`. Now that `one_element` is pure again, we don't lose solutions anymore:

```
?- unpack([A,B],[]).
A = [_5574, _5580|_5582],
B = [_5628, _5634|_5636] ;
A = [_5574, _5580|_5582],
B = [] ;
A = [],
B = [_5616, _5622|_5624] ;
A = B, B = [].
```

but

```
?- unpack([[a,b,c],[a],[b],[c,d]],Items).
Items = [a, b].
```

is still deterministic. I have not tried this solution in other Prologs, which might be missing the indexing, but it seems for SWI, this is a solution.

**Update**: Apparently GNU Prolog does not do this kind of indexing and overflows on cyclic lists:

```
| ?- Xs = [[] | Xs], unpack(Xs,Ys).

Fatal Error: global stack overflow (size: 32770 Kb, reached: 32768 Kb, environment variable used: GLOBALSZ)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it perfect, but it should be at least complete. I'm still unhappy with this choice between two implementations depending on the instantiation of ```Vs```.

Comment: `unpack([[X|Xs]], []).` fails incorrectly while `Xs = [_|_], unpack([[X|Xs]], []).` succeeds as expected.  Why do you use impure constructs at all? Edging cut?

Comment: Cut is a tempting way to make ```oe``` deterministic. I'll see if i can get rid of the impure constructs.

Comment: I found a solution, but I'm not sure how specific to SWI it is (it relies on indexing of ```[]``` and ```[_|_]``` arguments). What do you think?

Comment: Interesting, I have rather expected something along a reified Xs = [] and the like.

Comment: I tried a nested reified ```if_``` but that left choice points open. I'll play around with it tomorrow to check if i missed something.

Comment: GNU would need full expansion or GC.

Comment: `one_element` is  better called `one_element_t` to insist that the last arg is a truth value.

Comment: With [`set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) the goal `unpack([[a,b,c],[a],[b],[c,d]],Items).` shrinks to `unpack(["abc","a","b","cd"],Items).`. And `help("append")` is now written as `help(append)`

Answer (score 5):

After some thought, here is my implementation using `if_/3`:

```
unpacking(L,L1):-if_( =(L,[]), L1=[], unpack(L,L1)).

unpack([H|T],L):-if_(one_element(H), (H = [X],L=[X|T1],unpacking(T,T1)), unpacking(T,L)).

one_element(X, T) :-
   (  var(X) ->(T=true,X=[_]; T=false,X=[])
    ;  X = [_] -> T = true
    ;  X \= [_] -> T = false).
```

Some testcases:

```
?- unpacking([Xss],[]).

Xss = [].

?- unpacking([[1],[2,3],[4],[_,_|_]],U).
U = [1, 4].

?- unpacking([[1],[2,3],[4]],U).
U = [1, 4].

?- unpacking([[E]],[1]), E = 2.
false.

?- unpacking(non_list, []).
false.

?- unpacking([Xs],Xs).
Xs = [_G6221] ;
Xs = [].
```

---

**UPDATE**
To fix the case that @false referred in the comment we could define:

```
one_element([],false).
one_element([_],true).
one_element([_,_|_],false).
```

But this leaves some choice points...

Comment: `one_element([_|L], false), L = [_].` fails but `L = [_], one_element([_|L], false).` succeeds.

Comment: @false, but to fix this I don't think that unpacking predicate could be deterministic since we must leave some choice points in one_element/2 ??

Comment: Also I don't think this causes inconsistency in unpacking/2 predicate..

Comment: of course it does cause inconsistency! Take `?- unpacking([Xss],[]).` which fails with `Xss = [_,_|_]`.

Comment: OK...I get it but , can we fix that and still retain full determinism ?? A simple solution would be the updated answer but it has some choice points..??

Comment: Correctness first, then you can think about the rest.

Comment: What about the update version (as for correctness) ??

Comment: Correctness OK, now go for efficiency! Preferably **clean** efficiency.

Comment: The different versions are for one_element predicate only which is a small part, I prefer the second because it is clean and simple version (below the first update) but it leaves some choice points, the last attempt is more efficient in my opinion but it is not so pure (due to ground/2 ) so i think second is better...

Comment: ground/1 is certainly not needed.

Comment: Why? it offers determinism when the list is fully instantiated so no choice points wasted.... It is an attempt to reduce choice point when it is possible...If you think it is not needed due to impurity, that's why I would prefer second, Is it any other reason that you think it is not needed?

Comment: But it is efficient for, say `[[A,B,C],[V]]` while it could be determinate

Comment: Ok, I see maybe it wasn't a good idea, I will remove the last update...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143996/discussion-between-coder-and-false).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with a findall I dont think its what the bounty is for though ;)

```
unpacking(Lists,L1):-
   findall(I,(member(M,Lists),length(M,1),M=[I]),L1).

or 

unpacking2(Lists,L1):-
   findall(I,member([I],Lists),L1).
```

Comment: `unpacking([[E]],[1]), E = 2.` incorrectly succeeds.

Comment: `unpacking(non_list, []).` succeeds, too.

Comment: `unpacking([Xss],[]).` incorrectly fails, although `Xss=[], unpacking([Xss],[]).` succeeds.

Comment: `unpacking([Xs],Xs).` incomplete: There should be two answers/solutions: `Xs = [_A]` and `Xs = []`.

Comment: lots of improvements possible then :)

Comment: actually need to read about that findall thing. But thanks anyway

Comment: @Bl4ckCoding: findall/3 is a very low level tool that does not mix well with pure code.